# type error need string or buffer, file found in python

Tags: python

So when i write this chunk of code separately, it works fine but when i combine them together it give me typeError. Why is this happen? I don't get it when i wrote them separately it works fine. thanks in advance :)

```
def printOutput(start, end, makeList):

  if start == end == None:

      return

  else:

      print start, end

      with open('OUT'+ID+'.txt','w') as outputFile:#file for result output
          for inRange in makeList[(start-1):(end-1)]:
              outputFile.write(inRange)
          with open(outputFile) as file:
              text = outputFile.read()
      with open('F'+ID+'.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(textwrap.fill(text, width=6))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is at this line:

```
 with open(outputFile) as file:
```

`outputFile` is a file object (which is already open).  The `open` function wants a string (or something like it) which is the name of a file to open.

If you want to get the text back, you can always `outputFile.seek(0)` and then `outputFile.read()` again. (Of course, you'll have to open in `r+` mode for this to work.)

Perhaps an even better way to do this would be:

```
with open('OUT'+ID+'.txt','w') as outputFile:#file for result output
    text=''.join(makeList[(start-1):(end-1)])
    outputFile.write(text)
with open('F'+ID+'.txt', 'w') as ff:
    ff.write(textwrap.fill(text, width=6)) #Version of above file with text wrapped to 6 chars.
```

**EDIT**

This should work:

```
def printOutput(start, end, makeList):
    if start == end == None:
        return
    else:
        print start, end

        with open('OUT'+ID+'.txt','w') as outputFile:#file for result output
            text=''.join(makeList[(start-1):(end-1)])
            outputFile.write(text)
        with open('F'+ID+'.txt', 'w') as ff:
            ff.write(textwrap.fill(text, width=6)) #Version of above file with text wrapped to 6 chars.
```

Comment: what is the number inside seek() means and are you saying that i should use with open(outputFile, 'r+) as dile and outputFile.seek(0) and outputFile.read()

Comment: The number inside seek (`0`) is the file position.  In this case, 0 is the beginning of the file.  And yes, I am saying use `open(outputFile, 'r+)`, but rather than seeking, see my updated answer which gets the text all together and then writes it all at once, keeping a handle on the text to use with `textwrap`

Comment: I guess my goal is to write the file and format it so that only 6 character per line

Comment: @ChadD -- You have two files.  The first file `'OUT'+ID+'.txt'` and the second file `'F'+ID+'.txt'`.  The second file will have the text wrapped at 6 characters.  The first file won't.

Comment: i will update the code that i have.. i m not quite clear of what i should do but what i have above still doesnt work

Comment: it woks now.. one more question what is ff in write .. is it a command in module

Comment: @ChadD -- No, ff is simply the name of the file object that you're writing to (the file `'F'+ID+'.txt'`).  I changed the name because `file` is a builtin python type and while it isn't usually called directly, it's always a good idea to avoid shadowing builtins.

Comment: @mglison I just noticed that you change the word file.thanks again